# How to extract third party cookies of domain

Tags: cookies

How to extract third party cookies of domain and get name and value of  3 rd party cookies ? I tried using selenium webdriver but can only get domain level cookies not the third party . Please provide solution I will be thankful

Thanks

Comment: How did you try? Please post code and why you think the behavior is wrong.

Comment: 3 rd party cookies are not getting displayed.only domain level cookies are getting displayed